# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate, spring-oauth2

I am working on a spring boot application. The application has in-memory security authentication with some login details. From this application I want to access an API interface (to get user information) which is oauth2 type.

When I try to access the api using RestTemplate I get the following error.

```
class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken (org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The code where I am calling the interface in Controller class, is as follows:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Authenticated user name"+authentication.getName());
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken)authentication;
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient = oAuth2AuthorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getName());
    String tokenValue = oAuth2AuthorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    System.out.println("jwtAccessToken"+tokenValue);
    String url = "https://<url to interface>";
    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers =  new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization","Bearer "+tokenValue);

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
   ResponseEntity<List<Object>> responseEntity= restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
    List<Object> body = responseEntity.getBody();
    for (Object obj :
            body) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
```

I did the oauth2 configuration in the application.yaml file as shown below:

```
 aapp.api:
  base-url: https://<url to interface>

# Activate profile(s) HERE ['security' or 'tokenauth']
# or alternatively in a JVM argument ('-Dspring.profiles.active=security')
spring.profiles.active: security

---
# Use this profile to let spring-security automatically fetch and refresh tokens for you.
spring:
  profiles: security

# Supply credentials for authentication HERE!
aapp.api.security:
  username: some username
  password: pass

# Configure oauth2 registration and provider for api portal HERE!
spring.security.oauth2.client:
  registration:
    someClientId:
      authorization-grant-type: password
      client-id: <clientId>
      client-secret: <clientSecret>
  provider:
    coba:
      token-uri: https://<url to auth2 server>
```

I am new to spring security and oauth2. How can I solve this issue.

```
The spring security configuration I used is as follows:

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/test", "/logout").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/templates/**" ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/","/**","/release/**","/decline/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard?sortField=startDate&sortDir=asc",true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("pass")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```